# SwiftUI: Make Square view larger than its container view?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I would like to create a view that looks like this:
[image]

The `SquareView` is a view that I want to bring in a containing view in this case the ZStack and I want the `SquareView` to be offset up so that it gets clipped at the top by whatever amount of offset I want.

The `SquareView` is defined like this **and I cannot change it**:

```
struct SquareView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.gray.opacity(0.6))
            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
    }
    
}
```

The overall view is:

```
    VStack {
        
        ZStack {
            
            Color.red

            SquareView()
                .padding(.bottom, 80)
            
        }
        .aspectRatio(288/136, contentMode: .fit)
        .border(.yellow)
        .clipped()

        Spacer()
    }
```

It generates this:

[image]

The issue here is that the dimension of the square view is determined by the height of the parent ZStack, and so I cannot make the square view bigger like I want it to be almost filling the entire width of the ZStack and bleeding out to the top (although clipped).

How can I make the square view wider and grow out of the top of the ZStack while keeping the ZStack ratio and positioning

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired result, you need to modify the content mode of SqureView from **.fit** to **.fill** and adjust the padding accordingly (if needed).

Below is the sample code for example:

```
struct OverallView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           ZStack {
                Color.red
                SquareView()
                    .padding(.bottom, 80)
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 120) //Change as required
            }
            .aspectRatio(288/136, contentMode: .fit)
            .border(.yellow)
            .clipped()
        }
    }
}
```

and the SquareView is as follows:

```
struct SquareView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.gray.opacity(0.6))
            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I don't have access to SquareView that's why I said I cannot change it...